# Pass Values to GridView to TabActivity

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-tabactivity

in my App i have Gridview and TabActivity.
my Rice.class has gridview,
in MainActivity.class has tabActivity ,
myChild Tabs are FragmentA,FragmentB,FragmnetC.
i want pass my gridview index to FragmnetA.how can i slove this problem.

Rice.class

```
  public class Rice extends ActionBarActivity {
FragmentA fa;
GridView gridView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rice);
    gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewR);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyRAdapter(this));
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //Breakfast bf = (Breakfast) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index",i);
            startActivity(intent);

        }


    });

}




  }
  class MyRAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public MyRAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(450, 200));
        //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.back_1, R.drawable.back_2,
        R.drawable.back_3, R.drawable.back_4,
        R.drawable.back_5, R.drawable.back_6,
        R.drawable.back_11,

};

}
```

MainActivity.class

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFrAdapter(fragmentManager));


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int index = intent.getIntExtra("index",0);

}

 }
 class MyFrAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public MyFrAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(i==0){
        fragment = new FragmentA();

    }
    if(i==1){
        fragment = new FragmentB();
    }
    if(i==2){
        fragment = new FragmentC();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if(position == 0){
        return "Ingredient";
    }
    if(position == 1){
        return "Recipe";
    }
    if(position == 2){
        return "Summary";
    }
    return null;
}
 }
```

FragmentA.class

```
  public class FragmentA extends Fragment  {

TextView textView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    return view;


}


}
```

Comment: anyone can help me to slove this

Comment: sorry i cant understand this..

Comment: @Sameera hey have you done this or not still?

Comment: wait till i say download!!

Comment: may I have your code pleasE?

Comment: @Sameera may I have your code?

Comment: @pratik i got answer sir.

Comment: @pratik your are very kind.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        int mIndex;
        ViewPager viewPager=null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFrAdapter(fragmentManager));

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            mIndex = intent.getIntExtra("index",0);


        }



        class MyFrAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyFrAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if(i==0){
                fragment = new FragmentA().newInstance(mIndex);

            }
            if(i==1){
                fragment = new FragmentB();
            }
            if(i==2){
                fragment = new FragmentC();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            if(position == 0){
                return "Ingredient";
            }
            if(position == 1){
                return "Recipe";
            }
            if(position == 2){
                return "Summary";
            }
            return null;
        }

        }
    }


    //...



public class FragmentA extends Fragment  {

    TextView textView;
    int FragmentA_index;
    public static final String EXTRA_INDEX = "mypackage.index";

    public static FragmentA newInstance(int index) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(EXTRA_INDEX, index);

        FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentA_index = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_INDEX);


    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return view;


    }


}
```